Multiple Spring Configurations with same Class name not registered
I have a mustache generator that generates @Configuration for multiple API versions.
@Configuration("MyConfiguration{{majorVersion}}") // majorVersion is unique and passed by mustache
public class MyConfiguration { 
 // Rest of code
}

However, only one Configuration is registered. If I rename a class manually, then both Configurations are registered. The problem is that I do not want the generator to modify the class name because it also requires modifying the file name which would be a huge effort. Is there another way that all Configurations are registered although they have the same class name? I already tried @Configuration("giveSomeUniqueName) or @Component("someUniqueName") but it does not work.
If it does a difference: The classes are practically in the same package but in different gradle dependencies.

I guess the problem ist that you cannot have the same class in the same package. This error is not so obvious because the classes are in gradle dependencies. And I guess Spring is not able to handle that. I would appreciate it if you could confirm/rethink my guess

And I would also appreciate thoughts on a workaround
